# Is there a tutorial[s] on embedding a JavaScript app in someone else's site?

Tags: javascript, embed

I'm referring to the embed snippets (and associated files that get downloaded) for services like [Disqus](http://disqus.com)

Of course, the concept of giving someone some mark-up that pulls your JavaScript file down onto their site is simple in itself.

But when I look through the code [that gets pulled in] used by providers such as Disqus I see references to an `embedKey`, etc. Which seems to hint at some kind of additional security provision (other than simply expecting a web service authentication token).

So are there:

- Any tutorials on doing this kind of this 'correctly' and 'securely'?
- Are there any major considerations (other than ensuring you have no conflicts with existing script on the user's site) to make?

**Edit**

For an example of a key in use, see Wufoo's embed code at http://wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`embedKey`? sounds like an google maps `API key` or an adsense `unit ID`. It determines if that unit of code is valid, someone actually owns it, or points to a set of items in the server (like a chat room id perhaps).

As for conflict in code, you should wrap your code in an IFFE, that way, your variables won't leak to the surrounding code. What's not locally set assumes that you are getting it from outside. Declare your variables properly with `var` to avoid setting/changing the ones from the outside scope. Also, for name conflicts, local variables will take precedence.

```
//outsider code
var foo = 'foo';
var bar = 'bar';

//your code
(function(){
    var foo = 'baz';    //set a local foo
    bar = bam;          //outsider bar changed (no var);

    alert(foo); //baz
    alert(bar); //bam

}());

//some more outsider code
alert(foo); //foo, since  you protected your code
alert(bar); //bam, was wrecked by your code
```

Comment: Having looked at it further I believe the embedKey is used for submission tracking (i.e. a way of identifying unique submissions).